# Extract a substring from the "-" sign until the string´s end

Tags: vbscript

I´m looking for any way to remove substring from string starting in the "-" symbol until the string´s end.

```
Server Down - Windows Server BAWFM-055
Server Up - Linux Server LSWFM-089
```

In the first example the output will  be "Windows Server BAWFM-055"
In the second example the output will  be "Linux Server LSWFM-089"

Comment: @JNevill `Split` can't work here as there are `-` *inside* the result he needs

Comment: Oh! ha. I took the first sentence literally and didn't bother inspecting the string much.

Comment: [String.Mid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.mid(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need, or you can split by `_-_` (space - space)

Comment: @Rafalon that is not valid VBScript syntax.

Comment: Worth noting that the 3rd parameter of the [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5.aspx) function controls how many substrings are returned. Since there are hyphens in the rest of the string you want to set that parameter to 2, so that each string will be split only at the first hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

```
Trim(Mid(MyString, InStr(MyString, "-") + 1))
```

Where `MyString` is a variable holding your strings.
The `+1` is needed to Skip the minus sign and start at the next character.

Trim to remove eventual leading or trailing spaces.